# How to recognize UITap gesture in View inside a TableView > CollectionView

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a storyboard structure like this:

```
TableView
    Any View
    CollectionView
        CollectionViewCell
            CellView
        /CollectionViewCell
    /CollectionView
    Other views
    .
    .
/TableView
```

/View

As you can see, i have 2 dynamic controls (tableview and collection view inside this tableview), how can i recognize the UITap for the "CellView" inside a CollectioView that is also inside in another TableView?

I have tried with UITapGestureRecognizer, but doesn't work at all, i think is because the scroll tap for the table view or collectionview overrides the tap for my CellView.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is some next level inception style stuff isn't it... crikey. So to confirm you have a table view, and what each cell contains another tableview and collection view?

Comment: nope, i just have the first tableview to manage the scroll content for my view controller (it isn't dynamic cells), inside this one, i have the collection view, that containts the cell that i want to  get the UITap gesture

Comment: In that case you'd have to handle the 'rowselect' for the tableview, determine the tap location to get the cell for the collection view, then fire off the itemselected event for the collection view. The reason you'll have to do this manually is because the tableview 'handles' the tap event and as it's the top layer, it doesn't bubble down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a reference to your CellView by doing something like in the GetCell method:

```
UIView _cellView = yourCollection.ViewWithTag(yourViewTag);
```

Enable user interaction

```
_cellView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
```

Create TapGestureRecogniser object

```
UITapGestureRecognizer tapGesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer (TapThat);
tapGesture.CancelsTouchesInView = false;
tapGesture.NumberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
```

Create TapThat function
//Code for function

Finally, add the gesture recogniser
    _cellView.AddGestureRecogniser(tapGesture);

Also, refer to the following for more info

[Gesture Recognizer samples](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/touch/ios_touch_walkthrough/#Gesture_Recognizer_Samples)

[Using a tap gesture](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/input/touch/tap-gesture/)